# I have a button with text in it, but the text is not centered in the button. It is not in the middle, but more in the top left corner of the button

Tags: html, css, button, text

So how do I get the text to be in the middle of the button?

```
<style type="text/css">
a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #CC4A31;
color: #444;
border-radius: 9px;
position: absolute;
top: 16px;
left: 40px;
height: 50px;
width: 125px;
webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
</style>


<a href="">GameTrade</a>
```

Comment: that is not a button, that is a link.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following:

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
```

in your class.

If you add the same height and line-height, the text will always be centered.

That is in CSS:

```
height: 'x' px;
line-height: 'x' px;
```

You can see that here with different sizes. Observe how text is always centered despite the varying sizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/ywdHq/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
```

That should center the text in your `<a>` element. For any width. If you change the height of the button, change the `line-height` to the same value.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKesU/

Answer (score 0):

User text-align center for horizontal and use padding to center vertically (rather than specifying height). If you need a specific height, height = padding*2 + font-size

```
display: block;
padding: 20px 0px;
width: 125px;
text-align:center;
line-height:1em;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rYx6t/1/)

Comment: This solution works, but what if the width/height were requirements for the link style? Then it wouldn't work anymore

Comment: Edited accommodate this better

Comment: Where do you get the rule height = padding * 2 + font-size? In your own Fiddle example you can see that this rule is not accurate as you have a padding of 20 and a font-size of 14, but yet the height is 56 instead of 54.